# How Are Resources Released With Cloud Storage (Java Client)

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

The Cloud Firestore Java client has a `close` method which can be called to release resources which have been acquired.

[image]

Looking at the Cloud Storage Java Client there doesn't seem to be an equivalent close method. How I can ensure that all resources are freed up when using a Storage client?

Answer (score 1):

`Firestore` extends Java's `Autocloseable` interface whereas `Storage` does not. Hence why `Firestore` has a `close` method and `Storage` does not. The solution is to use a `try-with-resources` statement when acquiring a `Storage` resource.